# Connecting to firebase from react native

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to set up a react native project with firebase, without much success. The config data is fetched from here: https://console.firebase.google.com/project/my-project/overview, so everything there is generated automatically.

Here's my code for the setup:

```
const config = { 
    apiKey: "[MY-API-KEY]",
    authDomain: "[MY-AUTH-DOMAIN]",
    databaseURL: "[MY-DATABASE-URL]",
    storageBucket: "[MY-STORAGE-BUCKET]"
}

const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(config);
const usersRef = firebaseApp.database().ref('Users');
```

and later, at some point, if I try to run this:

```
usersRef.set({ test: "sdfsdf" });
```

nothing happens in the DB. I also can't get data from the database...

Any clue what I'm doing wrong in here?

Comment: Does your user have permission to access the database? On a newly created project only an authenticated user will have access, and you're not authenticating. See the first blue note on this page: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/retrieve-data

Comment: If you're running on Android try disable debug mode. FireBase has some weird problem when running on RN 0.31.

Comment: Thanks. I changed both read and write permissions to true, and it still isn't working... Debug is also disabled, as far as I can tell. Do I need to sign in or authenticate the user in any way?

Answer (score 2):

I've encountered a similar issue when importing my `database` reference object from another file. Basically, when you're performing the firebase app initialization in the same file than where you perform the `on` or `set` methods, that works. But once you try to import the `database` from another file, the config seems lost...I think it has to do with how ReactNative bundles the javascript, or something like that. Here's a workaround I came with :

**database.js**

```
import * as Firebase from 'firebase'

let HAS_INITIALIZED = false

const initFirebase = () => {
    if (!HAS_INITIALIZED) {
        const config = {
            apiKey: "**************",
            authDomain: "************",
            databaseURL: "*********",
            storageBucket: "*********",
        }

        Firebase.database.enableLogging(true)
        Firebase.initializeApp(config)
        HAS_INITIALIZED = true
    }
}

export const getDatabase = () => {
    initFirebase()
    return Firebase.database()
}
```

then, in **whatever-file-you-want.js**

```
import { getDatabase } from './database'

getDatabase().ref('...') // etc.
```